# Find the starting height from which a particle projected horizontally at $40$m/s travels $100$m

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

This question is in my homework: A particle is projected horizontally with speed 40m/s from a point A. It hits the ground 100m horizontally from A. Find the height of A.

Would it be possible for someone to guide me on how to start? $g=9.8$

Comment: You should probably be directing these questions to the physics SE, rather than the mathematics SE.

Comment: @BrianTung Sorry, im taught this as a maths module so i thought this would be the place

Comment: Yes, well, it's not entirely out of place here, either.  Just seems like it fits better over there, since the object of the questions seems more how to identify which physical laws to employ, rather than how to do the mathematics.

Comment: @BrianTung Also, this question would be closed on Physics site in pretty short order.

Comment: @NormalHuman: Can you explain why?  Is it just too homework-y?  Too simple?  What are they expecting?

Comment: @BrianTung They don't accept "here's a problem, please help"; for details see their site.

Comment: @NormalHuman: Interesting, thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: @BrianTung ... and as a result, this homework [ends up here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1570097).

Comment: @NormalHuman I posted to physics SE first but i was rejected. I dont have any other avenues of support to use so i am turning here.

Comment: Maybe you should take a little while to process the two answers I already gave and see if you can work out how to do this new one.

Comment: There's https://www.physicsforums.com/ and I'm sure plenty of others. Internet $\ne $ Stack Exchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find the time it takes for the projectile to travel $100$ m horizontally, given a horizontal speed of $40$ m/s.  Call this time $t$.  Then use the formula $d = \frac{gt^2}{2}$ to obtain the vertical distance that the projectile falls in that time.